# Chrome Developer Tools delay on localhost

Tags: windows, google-chrome, iis, visual-studio-2013, console

After format the PC and install Windows 10, I install the Chrome last version and enable the IIS from control panel.

So when I open the developer tools when I'm browsing a website on my localhost  , there is a delay (Lag) in the Elements section, it's too slow.

Is there a way to fix that proplem  ?

Comment: Guys , anyone has a advice or help please ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed , the lag was from visual studio , there is something called "Enable browser link" it was writing to the browser directly if there is any change, by uncheck it the developer tools ( Elements tab ) is working very fast and prefect.